# DJangoCMS - Outputting number of menu children to menu template

Tags: django, menu, navigation, parent-child, django-cms

Within DjangoCMS I'd like to display the number of children a page has in the navigation.

I have a menu item called "Careers" and I'd like it to say "Careers (2)" if there are 2 sub-pages within that page in the site tree.

Is this possible?

I can target the right menu item in menu.html but need to dynamically generate the number somehow.

```
{% if child.get_menu_title|slugify == "careers" %}<span>1</span>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Still trying, and even {{ child.children.count }} doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I more or less determined that without faffing with models (which I can't do) I solved the problem with some nifty CSS and JavaScript. Not a wonderful result, but it's sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it myself and you can do:

```
{% if child.children %} <span>{{ child.children|length }}</span>{% endif %}
```